# PHP CURL POST get authenticated and send POST request after redirect by CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, curl

In order to create a new user on a website I need to send a POST request to this URL:

https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/

sending the fields "Prepagata_codice=[chosen username]" and "Prepagata_password=[chosen password]"

The page where I need to send the POST request need authentication and redirect to the login page.

I use the following code but I'm not able to be authenticated, instead I'm redirected to the login page.

My question is how can I handle the authentication after the redirect and send my POST request?

I have try everything but I'm not able to found a solution, please any help is really appreciated.

```
// Set the URL for page to send the post request for create a new user
$url = "https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/";

// Set username and password for authentication
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

# Set the cURL options.
$options = [
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $username . ":" . $password,
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => "Prepagata_codice=" . $_GET[user] . "&Prepagata_password=" . $_GET[pass]
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// Do request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Get status code
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Show statusCode and response
echo $statusCode;
echo $response;

// close cURL
curl_close($ch);
```

Thankyou very much for your answer. I was able now to login sending the fields and not using the CURLOPT_USERPWD. However Maybe I was not clear in my question. The URL I posted in my question is not for login but is used to add a new WIFi  user on their system. The Prepagata[code] and Prepagata[password] are fields expected in the page for the indicated URL in order to add a new user. Now I have achive to login with the following code:

```
$url = "https://wifinext.internavigare.com/userGroups/";

// Set username and password for authentication
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

# Set the cURL options.
$options = [
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $username . ":" . $password,
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => "UserGroupsUser[username]=" . $username . "&UserGroupsUser[password]=" . $password
];
```

But when I send the next POST request to the URL $url = "https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/";

with this code:

```
$user = $_GET[user];
$pass = $_GET[pass];
$url = "https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$options = [
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $username . ":" . $password,
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => "Prepagata[codice]=" . $user . "&Prepagata[password]=" . $pass
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
```

I'm just redirected to the page for add a new user but the user is not added.

Comment: Solved! I miss to pass some other fields required but the page was not helpful to show any error

Comment: you still forget to urlencode stuff everywhere, so things will get easily corrupted. in my code snippets, i actually let `http_build_query` urlencode the stuff for me, but the easiest way is to use `urlencode()` - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they don't use a login scheme natively supported by curl, so you can drop this part `CURLOPT_USERPWD         => $username . ":" . $password` - at best, its a waste of bandwidth, at worst, it'll confuse the web server and refuse to log you in.

quote: `sending the fields "Prepagata_codice=[chosen username]" and "Prepagata_password=[chosen password]"`
 - no, that's not at all what i'm getting. in my tests, the fields are

```
$params = array (
        'UserGroupsUser' => array (
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'rememberMe' => 0 
        ),
        'yt0' => 'Login' 
);
```

and the easiest way to handle http redirects, is to enable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, with that, curl will handle http redirects for you automatically. also in my tests, the login POST url is actually `https://wifinext.internavigare.com/userGroups`, not `https://wifinext.internavigare.com/prepagataAnagrafica/creaUtente/`

also its POSSIBLE that they are trying to protect against CSRF attacks by validating the `Referrer` header, refusing to log you in if its wrong, easiest way around that is to enable `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` and make a normal GET request to the login page first.

also, you *PROBABLY* need a cookie session before attempting to login, easiest way to do that, is to set CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, now curl will handle cookies for you automatically.

and you *DEFINITELY* need to handle cookies in order to stay logged in - its this cookie which is tied to your login. if you don't send the cookie with the next request after logging in, the server won't remember your login, and will send you the login page again. so enable cookies.

and protip, whenever you're debugging curl code, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE , it prints lots of useful debugging info, like the http status codes, and any redirects received.

also, check the return type of curl_setopt_array! if there was a problem setting any of your settings, it returns bool(false), and you should use curl_error() to find the error.

also, in your code, you don't urlencode $_GET[user] / $_GET[password], so if they contain any characters with special meanings in urlencoded format, you'll send the wrong credentials and won't get logged in (this includes `&`,`=`,`@`, spaces, and many other characters), so urlencode them.

here's an example logging in, using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php , a convenience wrapper around curl_, taking care of cookies, response body file, verbose debugging info files, referrer header, checking the return type of curl_setopt_array & throwing an exception if your options could not be set, etcetc:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$username = '???';
$password = '???';
$url = 'https://wifinext.internavigare.com/userGroups';
$hc = new hhb_curl ( $url, true );
$hc->exec (); // getting a referer, and a cookie session
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'UserGroupsUser' => array (
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password,
                        'rememberMe' => 0 
                ),
                'yt0' => 'Login' 
        ) ) 
) );
$hc->exec ( $url );//actually logging in.
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );
```

(with a real $username / $password, it probably will be able to log in)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I have update my question with the new results